# Recurrent events analysis software (python)

Tags: python, survival, cox-model, recurrent-events

I am looking for tips for adapting usual survival analysis software to **recurrent events** analysis, within the framework of the Cox regression. Specifically: whether it is always possible to do? What are the limitations? Can this be done for the birth& death process?

If you can offer software, where the analysis of recurrent events is already implemented, it could be helpful as well.
(At the moment I am using `pysurvival` package that does not provide special capability for recurrent events analysis.)

Comment: Asking for software recommendations is off-topic here, but this Q is also about methodology "tips for adapting usual survival analysis software ", which is on-topic. Could you please reformulate to focus on the later?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classic [book](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387987842) by Terry Therneau and Patricia Grambsch, "Modeling Survival Data: Extending the Cox Model," devotes chapter 8 to modeling multiple events per subject. It covers recurrent events of the same type, ordered and unordered events, competing events, and multi-state models. If you can't get a copy, much of that material is also in a [Mayo Clinic Technical Report](https://www.mayo.edu/research/documents/biostat-58pdf/doc-10027288) by Therneau.

Briefly, there are two major issues that need to be addressed. First:

> A major issue in extending proportional hazards regression models to this situation is intrasubject correlation.  (Therneau and Grambsch, page 169)

One accepted way to deal with this is to do standard modeling but use robust estimates of coefficient (co)variances.

Second is the type of recurrence pattern you expect. For example, if there is a single event type for which the time clock resets to 0 at each event (a renewal process), then you might use the simple (`time`,`status`) data format,* where `time` is recorded as time since study entry for the first event for an individual and the time since the prior event for the second and later events. You then do a standard Cox regression, with an `id` variable keeping track of which events correspond to which individual so that you can construct the robust error estimates.

For more complicated situations you will probably need to use a counting-process data format in which you specify (`timeStart`,`timeStop`,`status`) for the period leading up to each event or censoring time. That format (also used for time-dependent covariate values) is available in the Python [`lifelines` package](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) along with a `cluster` variable option to handle robust variance estimates. So I suspect that could work for recurrent events of a single type.

For competing-event or multi-state models, the `status` in the (`timeStart`,`timeStop`,`status`) format needs to be a multi-category factor rather than a simple binary event/censored indicator, and models need to be specified for each allowed transition between states. I don't think that `lifelines` handles such models, but they are handled in the R [`survival` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=survival). A [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/survival.pdf) in the package outlines how to implement such models.

---

*This specification of a single `time` (since `time=0`) and a binary event/censoring `status` seems to be the only format allowed by `pysurvival`, at a first glance.

Answer (score 1):

No need to adapt, you can use the following library: https://reliability.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Mean%20cumulative%20function.html
Its also worth checking out some of the reda package documentation (r).
The reliability github profile is also very useful: https://github.com/MatthewReid854/reliability/tree/master/docs/API/Nonparametric

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/350421)